# Uploading files --> Array / single file

Tags: php, file, upload

i've got to forms which both send files to "upload.php".
"Upload.php" moves the uploaded file(s) to target directory and generates a thumbnail.

- The problem/question: One form sends only **one** file, so in this
  case upload.php doesn't get a $_FILES-array. (input type="file" name="file">). This form is sent from a mobile device and i don't know how to change the files object into an array, so i can't change this
- The other form sends a file array with one or more files (input type="file" name="file[]">.

In my upload.php i walk through the files array with a foreach:

```
foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $new_image_name = $key.$_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $dest=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."uploads/".$new_image_name;
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $dest);
    // and so on...
}
```

With the form which sends a file array it works perfect.
But as you can imagine the form which sends only one file doesn't pass the foreach.

So whats the best solution to get upload.php working for both forms?
My idea: upload.php first has to check, if $Files is a array and if not converting it to an array. then foreach will get always an array

Comment: All you need to do is use the same file name in both forms, `name="file[]"`. The square brackets are what's making PHP generate the array structure.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if files are uploaded, $_FILE variable is always an array where you upload single or multiple files.

So lets say about multiple files, Typical mapping for $_FILE variable for multiple file is like..

```
    Array
    (
        [file] => Array
            (
                [name] => Array
                    (
                        [file1] => MyFile.txt
                        [file2] => MyFile.jpg
                    ),

                [type] => Array
                    (
                        [file1] => text/plain
                        [file2] => image/jpeg
                    ),

                [tmp_name] => Array
                    (
                        [file1] => /tmp/php/php1h4j1o
                        [file2] => /tmp/php/php6hst32
                    ),

                [error] => Array
                   (
                       [file1] => UPLOAD_ERR_OK
                       [file2] => UPLOAD_ERR_OK
                   ),

                [size] => Array
                   (
                       [file1] => 123
                       [file2] => 98174
                   )
        )
)
```

so, for multiple file upload, lets say if I want to access ['tmp_name'] from multiple file upload, like, `$temp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` then `$temp_name` will contain an array,

The difference is, for the single file upload, `$temp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`; `$temp_name` will contain a string, one string of the uploaded single file.

Now, we can actually cast it to array and make it look like multiple upload, again for single file if I write `$temp_name = (array)$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` now `$temp_name` file will contain an array, which is basically that single string, but wrapped in an array which index is 0.

Now both single and multiple file upload looks similar right?

So based on that, you can modify your code like..

```
// lets be sure that $_FILES are not empty 
if( !empty( $_FILES ) ) { // I might did this check already, if so, ignore it

    // now we are going to type cast the $_FILE variable as an array

      foreach( (array) $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){

       $file_names = (array) $_FILES['file']['name']; // just ensuring that single file name is in array format

       $new_image_name = $key.$file_names[$key]; // no worries about the $key! 
       $file_tmp = $tmp_name[$key];

       $dest=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."uploads/".$new_image_name;
       move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $dest);
        // and so on...
      }

    }
```

So now, this will work for both of your cases, if there's only 1 file, (array) casting in the foreach `foreach( (array) $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )` will ensure that `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` will contain an array with at least 1 tmp_name, and for multiple uploads, its already an array!

same thing I did at `$file_names = (array) $_FILES['file']['name'];` to ensure there will be always an array of names which will at least contain 1 name for singe file upload case.

you can access other values in the same way.

Hope it make sense :)

Answer (score 0):

It's look good. Just your html must look like this for one file upload:

```
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     <input type="file" name="file[]">
     <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default save_change_btn">upload photo</button>
 </form>
```

And this for 2 files upload:

```
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     <input type="file" name="file[]">
     <input type="file" name="file[]">
     <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default save_change_btn">upload photo</button>
 </form>
```